# Prometheus in Docker container not showing all metrics

Tags: docker, prometheus

I'm running Prometheus in a Docker container, as I have to monitor the utilization of the resources of the container itself. But when I browse in localhost:9090 to see the graphs, metrics as "container_memory_usage_bytes" or similar are not available. This is what I see:

[image]

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Have you configured Prometheus to scrape Cadvisor, and is that scrape suceeding?

Comment: I have a container with cadvisor and one with Prometheus..how can I link them? cadvisor is set on port 8080 and prometheus on 9090.. i tried to set in prometheus.yml targets: ['localhost:8080'] but it doesn't work..thanks for the help

Comment: I also modified targets with localhost:9090 and cadvisor:8080, and then run prometheus with --link cadvisor:cadvisor, but doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Which OS are you running?
If this is CentOS/Amazon linux, you may need to provide additional mount points for your cadvisor container.

Basically:

- Mount /cgroup as well.
- Make cadvisor a privileged container